# using jQuery .promise() to call clearInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval, promise

I have been experimenting a lot with setInterval and clearInterval recently, for creating my own custom effects and one of the things that I have been working on is an efficient way to clear an interval whilst staying out of the global scope. I am trying to improve readability and explore possible performance boosts by using .promise() to call clearInterval() (the below is an example of what I'm trying to do):

```
//caller is a collection of elements
function performEffect(caller) {
   var interval = setInterval(function() { caller.next(); }, 500);
   caller.promise().done(function() { interval = clearInterval(interval); });
}
```

Up until recently, I had been setting and clearing the interval using an embedded function (example):

```
function performEffect(caller) {
   var interval;
   var count = 0;
   var len = caller.length;

   if (count >= len) {
       interval = clearInterval(interval);
   }

   var tmr = function () {
       interval = setInterval(function () { effectFunciton(count++); }, 100);
   }
}
```

P.S. I'm sorry for not posting the original - my versioning system was corrupted. Also, I know that this example is kind of silly, since I could easily use a for-loop or a .each(), but it's just an example - I do have instances where I do not want to use a loop.

This is my first post, so I apologize ahead of time if I do something different from the accepted practice. Please let me know if there is anything I can do to improve my posts in the future - I'm always open to constructive criticism :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use deferreds for this.  I wrote an example on jsfiddle a little while ago that may give you some insight.

http://jsfiddle.net/landau/M3Lj4/

From your code, it looks like you are misunderstanding deferreds in general or there isn't enough code here to tell what you are doing. Promises hides `resolving` and `rejecting` functionality

Basically,

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();
var promise = deferred.promise();

// This will only run once
var timer = setInterval( function () {
    deferred.resolve();
}, 1000);

promise.done(function () {
    clearInterval( timer );
});
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I've been looking for. I think I may be misunderstanding deferreds a bit so I will check read more about those before continuing. Thanks so much.

Comment: Great, if this is the answer to your question, please click the checkbox. :)